# WindowsDefender Trojan warning after compiling c program with string.h and stdio.h?

Tags: c, windows, trojan, windows-defender

As you will see I am not good in c programming, still learning but my WindowsDefender is yelling at me for compiling this code with MinGW from Codeblocks IDE.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

char *strings[] = {"test", "test"};
char *newStr;
int i;
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
   strcat(newStr, strings[i]);
   printf("%s\n", newStr);
}

return 0;
}
```

[image: This is the Warning from Windows Defender]

Can you help me with that I don't know what this is about. This can't be a normal issue mh?

Comment: very crazy is the fact that it has become two view directly after posting this, someone watching?

Comment: Change `char *newStr` to `char newStr[10];`.

Comment: `char newStr[10];` is still UB. Need: `char newStr[10] = { 0 };` to force a starting EOS in the string so the _first_ `strcat` works correctly. Alternate: above the `for` do: `newstr[0] = 0;`

Comment: Whenever a question is posted, anybody watching a particular tag (e.g. the `c` tag) will see their browser tab change. Or, on the page, it will show an alert phrase. So, this is quite common.

Comment: Sorry but what is EOS? Funny fact, I was installing HxD Editor and after execution an error showed up Exception EOSError in module HxD.exe.... A call to an OS function failed. Does it have to do with the problem above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been having this for several days recently when I compile simple programs in C in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Community edition. For example this one.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        a--;
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
        if (a == 8) break;
    }
}
```

The problem isn't with your program (or mine) but Windows Defender has become overly paranoid and is erroneously identifying normal compiled code. I get the same Trojan warning as you. The danger is if we turn off Defender for crying wolf that a real virus could slip onto an unguarded Pc. I'm tempted to switch to a different a/v like AVG or switch into hyper-V and compile programs on Ubuntu with GCC or clang.

Comment: yeah, but thats a mess. When I am really powerful on linux systems I will ban windows...